# How to print string and edit it after in console?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

Question is about print() Python function. Is there any way to print some text with ability to edit it after? For example after execution code `print("some text")` i cant change this string if i want to erase word 'text' in console. But i need. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this one but with `\r` you can erase the line of text.

You can also use this code:

```
print ('some text'),
sys.stdout.flush()
...
print ('\rtext') ',
sys.stdout.flush()
```

hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

print('b', end="\r")
sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
```

Add a sleep to see how it works.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

print('b', end="\r")
sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions,
if you want to do more fancy terminal manipulations there is the [curses package](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) which let you much more control.